# No consigo eliminar todos los espacios de un string

Tags: java

Buenas,

No sé si estoy haciendo algo mal. Tan sólo quiero eliminar los espacios a cada extremo de un string, para ello uso `.trim()`. El código que tengo:

```
String quedan = doc.select(".c-price .text-muted").first().text(); //save $1.40 • 6 days remaining            
String[] parts = quedan.split("•");
String remaining = parts[1];
String[] partes = remaining.split("day");
String dias_remaining = partes[0].trim().replace(" ", "");
dias_remaining = dias_remaining.trim(); //me devuelve: " 6" en vez de "6", con lo que no me deja pasarlo a int en el siguiente paso. 
int dias_remaining_int = Integer.parseInt(dias_remaining);
```

No veo que sea un carácter especial el espacio que hay justo delante del número 6.

Comment: Pues tiene toda la pinta de que sea un carácter especial. Igual te va mejor usar una expresión regular "^\\D*(\\d+)\\D*$"

Comment: @JetLagFox ¿Puedes poner el texto que quieres tratar?

Comment: @SJuan76 Al final lo he solucionado usando esto `.replaceAll("\u00a0", "")`

Comment: @nachfren Está puesto en el primer comentario `save $1.40 • 6 days remaining`

Comment: @JetLagFox Pon ese comentario como respuesta y, pasado el tiempo necesario, márcala como respuesta aceptada.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Hecho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo he resuelto:

`.replaceAll("\u00a0", "")`

Al parecer se trataba de un carácter especial.